# Numpy.where in a list of arrays, searching for an entire array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of arrays, and I am looking the position of a specific array:

```
import numpy as np
c = [np.array([0, 0]), np.array([-1,  0]), np.array([ 0, -1]), np.array([0, 1]), np.array([1, 0])]
n = np.array([0,-1])

np.where(c==n)
# array([[ True, False],
       [False, False],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True, False],
       [False, False]])
```

I guess it's comparing elemnet by element? 
 How do I return only the position where *both* `x` and `y` are `True`, without having to do another `np.where` to search `[True, True]`?

Comment: `np.where(c==n` returns `(array([0, 2, 2, 3]), array([0, 0, 1, 0]))` for me

Comment: You are looking for `np.equal(c, n).all(axis=1)`

Comment: Great thanks @Georgy, if you write that an answer I 'll accept it

Comment: Most probably this question was asked before. I'll try to search for a duplicate, and if I won't find anything, I will write an answer.